# Database.convertLead() DML count

Tags: apex, governorlimits

Database.convertLead() will create an account, a contact and optionally an opportunity.

I ran the conversion for a lead  using the following code.

```
Lead myLead = [SELECT ID,Status FROM Lead WHERE Id = '00Q9000000nuxhO'];
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
Leadstatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);
Database.convertLead(lc);
```

It created an Account, an Opportunity and a Contact.

**So ideally it should have been a 3 DML statements  right ?
But in the log it shows only 1 DML statement.**

Can anyone explain the rationale behind this ?

Comment: Doesn't 1 dml statement seem more "ideal" than 3?

Comment: I know...but I am just curious to know why it is considered a single statement :)

Comment: Can you add a debug on `Limits.getDmlStatements()` after the `convertLead` call just to make it more explicit?

Comment: `Database.convertLead(...)` runs `insert List<sObject>` maybe, the only reasonable explanation that I could imagine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated on [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> Calls to the following methods count against the number of DML queries issued in a request.
>
> - `Approval.process`
> - `Database.convertLead`
> - `Database.emptyRecycleBin`
> - `Database.rollback`
> - `Database.setSavePoint`
> - `delete` and `Database.delete`
> - `insert` and `Database.insert`
> - `merge` and `Database.merge`
> - `undelete` and `Database.undelete`
> - `update` and `Database.update`
> - `upsert` and `Database.upsert`
> - `System.runAs`

Every time you call any of them, the system increments the DML counter by 1, regardless of how many records were processed by the statement.

Comment: @AdrianLarson of course not :p

Comment: Done! Again, +1 for finding a reference for this one. Didn't even occur to me.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks! My arrow keys are not working quite right just now, so that would have taken me ages.

Comment: Python ftw. `print('\n'.join('>- \`%s\`' % operation for operation in '''<bullets>'''.split('\n')))`

Answer (score 4):

I can't verify this is what happens with `Database.convertLead`, but you can insert up to 10 different types of `SObject` in one `List<SObject>` even without using that method, as astutely noted by [@Joca](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4347/joca) in the comments.

```
insert new List<SObject>
{
    new Account(...),
    new Contact(...),
    new Opportunity(...)
};
system.assertEquals(1, Limits.getDmlStatements());
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that 1 DML statement can insert multiple records. The system created an Account, an Opportunity and a Contact, all with a single Apex DML statement: `Database.convertLead(lc);`

The number of records created is irrelevant to the number of statements used.